# Placing sub-figures captions in top and left-handed

Tags: graphics, captions

The way I am using to collect many sub-figures in one figure is like that:

MWE:

```
\begin{figure}[b!]
\begin{center}
$%
\begin{array}[t]{cc}
\text{\includegraphics{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate.eps}} & \text{%
\includegraphics{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate.eps}} \\ 
\text{(a)} & \text{(b)} \\ 
\text{\includegraphics{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate.eps}} & \text{%
\includegraphics{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate.eps}} \\ 
\text{(c)} & \text{(d)}%
\end{array}%
$%
\end{center}
\caption{title}
\label{fig:FIGURE2.8}
\end{figure}
```

and the result:

[image]

but what I want actually is to put sub-figures captions in the top (BOLD left-handed) like in the following image:

[image]

how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete small document, which we can copy and compile as it is.

Comment: Welcome to TEX-SE! Please always provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Otherwise we do not know which packages you are using. Also you may be interested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117087/121799).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use an `array` environment to position the graphs. Instead, I would load the `subcaption` package and use its machinery to arrange the graphs and associated captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.25\baselineskip,justification=raggedright,
              font={footnotesize,bf},labelsep=space,labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
\caption{flow\,=\,damped oscilator, CMRO2 coupled}  
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate1.eps}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}
\caption{flow\,=\,gamma variate convolutions, CMRO2 coupled} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate2.eps} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\caption{\dots}  
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate3.eps}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\caption{\dots}  
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{PHDImages/Chapitre2/gamma-variate4.eps} 
\end{subfigure}

\caption{title}
\label{fig:FIGURE2.8}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```